# Plotting Stacked Histogram for Time-series data

Tags: python, visualization, data-analysis

Given the dataset:

```
timestamp                     item       itemcount
2019-03-18 07:40:08.759        A          10
2019-03-18 08:40:08.759        B          5
..................................................
2019-05-20 07:40:08.759        D          4
2019-05-21 07:40:08.759        E          8
```

I want to plot stacked histogram like: 
[image: stacked histogram]

where the x-axis should be the date and y axis the itemcount and stack will be each item. I want the graph with subplots for every month.

I am new here so will be happy to get any feedback on my mistakes. Thank you.

here's one sample code i found online which plots the same graph in the figure above.

```
  # Import Data
df = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/selva86/datasets/raw/master/mpg_ggplot2.csv")

# Prepare data
x_var = 'manufacturer'
groupby_var = 'class'
df_agg = df.loc[:, [x_var, groupby_var]].groupby(groupby_var)
vals = [df[x_var].values.tolist() for i, df in df_agg]

# Draw
plt.figure(figsize=(16,9), dpi= 80)
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(i/float(len(vals)-1)) for i in range(len(vals))]
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(vals, df[x_var].unique().__len__(), stacked=True, density=False, color=colors[:len(vals)])

# Decoration
plt.legend({group:col for group, col in zip(np.unique(df[groupby_var]).tolist(), colors[:len(vals)])})
plt.title(f"Stacked Histogram of ${x_var}$ colored by ${groupby_var}$", fontsize=22)
plt.xlabel(x_var)
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.ylim(0, 40)
plt.xticks(ticks=bins, labels=np.unique(df[x_var]).tolist(), rotation=90, horizontalalignment='left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you include the necessary information and tags on your used framework/language and your code tried so far? (e.g. R & ggplot vs. Python & seaborn or matplotlib or...)

Comment: any library or framework is okay for me.
I tried using matplotlib but was not able to do it.

Comment: so I can assume you use Python? (I'd add that to the question and tags because an R answer is unlikely to get you to your goal then). Can you show the matplotlibe code you tried so far, it may be easier to fix that instead of starting from 0.

Comment: yeah... I have no idea on how to plot this kind of graph. I have this dataset and wanted to plot a similar graph and found one online.

Comment: I have edited my question with the code

Comment: You can simply use the pretty example shown by @bombadilhom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53899544/7306659)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses plotnine which is based on R ggplot and the grammar of graphics.

Generally you have to transform the timestamp to months first and then understand that:

X = Months
Y = itemcount
Group = item

This should help also for your matplotlib solution!

````py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp']).month

p = (ggplot(pdf, aes(x = 'month', y = 'itemcount',fill='item')) + geom_bar( Star = 'identity',position='fill')

# fill here acts the same as group in matplotlib
```
````

Comment: getting an error msg as: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic

Comment: @naman use stat = 'identity' in the geom_bar function.

Comment: thank you for your solution.

Comment: Can you suggest me how I can plot subplots for every month. I will take x as day. @Fnguyen

Comment: @naman you should really post a new question with reproducible sample data.

Comment: will do that.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may apply [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) to your project. There is a free [Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/developer/) for developers you can download and with the [Wolfram Client Library for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) you can use these functions in Python.

You may use the [`DateHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateHistogram.html) function for your plot.  However, lets create an example data set in Python first.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_date = datetime(2019, 9, 27)
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=365)

random.seed(91827364)

data = {
        'timestamp' : list(map(
                                lambda r: start_date + (end_date - start_date) * r, 
                                [random.random() for i in range(100)]
                            )),
        'item' : random.choices(['A','B','C','D','E','F'], k=100),
        'itemcount' : [random.randrange(1,20) for i in range(100)]
       }

dfTimes = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

dfTimes.head()
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `DateHistogram` and [`WeightedData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) on `dfTimes` the plot can be generated.

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr

wolfSession = WolframLanguageSession()

dh = wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.DateHistogram(
        wl.Query(
            wl.RightComposition(wl.GroupBy(wlexpr('#["item"]&')), wl.KeySort), 
            wl.RightComposition(wl.Values, wl.Transpose, wl.Apply(wl.WeightedData)),
            wl.RightComposition(['timestamp', 'itemcount'], wl.Values)
        )(dfTimes),
        'Month', 'Count',
        PlotLabel='Sum(Item Count)',
        ChartLayout="Stacked",
        ChartLegends=wl.Automatic,
        DateTicksFormat=['MonthNameShort',' ','YearShort'],
        ImageSize=wl.Large,
        ChartBaseStyle=wl.Opacity(1),
        ChartStyle=wl.ColorData(["Indexed","Sunrise"])
    )
)
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
wolfSession.terminate()
```

If you environment does not render `dh` then you can view the chart by [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html)ing in one of the supported [Raster Image Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RasterImageFormats.html) or [Vector Graphics Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/VectorGraphicsFormats.html).

```
wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.Export(
        '<path with image filename>', 
        dh
        )
    )
)
```

In Wolfram Language with a [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) `dfTimes` containing the same data then, for comparison, the same chart is (`Dataset` gets a bit of syntax sugar with [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html)).

```
DateHistogram[
 dfTimes[
  GroupBy[#["item"] &] /* KeySort,
  Values /* Transpose /* Apply[WeightedData],
  {"timestamp", "itemcount"} /* Values
  ],
 "Month", "Count",
 PlotLabel -> "Sum(Item Count)",
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ChartLegends -> Automatic,
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "YearShort"},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[1],
 ChartStyle -> ColorData[{"Indexed", "Sunrise"}]]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Tried the solution. But got stuck into many errors as: ''WolframKernelException: Cannot locate a kernel automatically. Please provide an explicit kernel path"

Comment: @naman  You must [download the free Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/developer/).